# C# httpclient add parameters to body

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am trying to connect to an API using the following format using the GET command:

HTTP Request Format:
o Request Headers:
Authorization:"Bearer NapDjG**************************************"
o Request Body:
username:" test_user@gocanvas.com"

I am having difficulty getting the user name parameter into the body of the call:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token_auth.client_secret);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

var nvc = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", token_auth.client_id));

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, token_auth.api_domain + option);
var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
```

** multipartContent.Add(new StringContent("test_user@gocanvas.com"), "username");**
request.Content = multipartContent;

```
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return responseBody;
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEx6p.png)

I am getting the following error:

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
Source=System.Net.Http
StackTrace:
at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
at GoCanvasApp.API.ApiTokenDetails.d__28.MoveNext() in

Comment: You say that you are trying to user HTTP GET, but in the code you have ```HttpMethod.Post``` in your HTTP Request Message....simething does not line up